# How to call, Hang up, put on hold and unhold calls using Twilio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, twilio

I have a Twilio number and I understood that in order to do those 4 actions(Call, Hang up, put onhold and unhold calls) I need to create a conference  call, but I don't understand how I add my Twilio number to the conference and how do I add another number of a mobile of a client. For example, if my Twilio number is " +9728888888" and the customer's I want to call to mobile number is "+9725555555" – I want code examples of : 
1.  Calling the customer(from Twilio number " +9728888888" to mobile number "+9725555555")
2.  Hold the call
3.  UnHold the cold
4.  Hangout the call.

I'm using **Twilio NuGet on web api project**.  Can you give me the  code examples , considering the numbers I gave(Twilio and mobile) for all of those four scenarios above? I would really appreciate it.

BTW, I saw the code example on their site:

```
using Twilio.TwiML;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        var dial = new Dial();
        dial.Conference("moderated-conference-room",
            startConferenceOnEnter: false);
        response.Dial(dial);

        System.Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

but it doesn't acknowledge the Twilio or the mobile phone or even the Twilio authentication so I'm not sure how can it work..

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to make a call from your Twilio number to a end user and put both your agent and the user into a conference call then this is the way that I would do it. I am not, however, a C# developer, so while I'll try to give code samples I'm not experienced in .NET web api projects.

You say that you are using the [Twilio package from Nuget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp), that's a good start.

First up, you need to generate a call to your agent and place them in the conference call to wait for the user. To do this, you would [use the Twilio REST API to place the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). That code looks a bit like this

```
const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const string authToken = "your_auth_token";
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var to = new PhoneNumber("AGENT_PHONE_NUMBER");
var from = new PhoneNumber("+9728888888");
var call = CallResource.Create(
  to,
  from,
  url: new Uri("http://example.com/conference")
);
```

When this call connects with the agent's number [Twilio will make a request to the URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) that is sent to the API. [Your application needs to respond to tell Twilio what to do with the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/your_response). In this case, we should put the agent into a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) to wait for the user. Within this action we also need to generate a call to the user.

```
public IHttpActionResult Conference()
{
    // make the call to the user
    var to = new PhoneNumber("+9725555555");
    var from = new PhoneNumber("+9728888888");
    var call = CallResource.Create(
      to,
      from,
      url: new Uri("http://example.com/user_conference")
    );
    // return the TwiML
    var response = new VoiceResponse();
    var dial = new Dial();
    dial.Conference("Conference", endConferenceOnExit: true);
    response.Dial(dial);
    Ok(response.ToString());
}
```

Note: I've set the agent side of this conference to [`endConferenceOnExit: true`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-endConferenceOnExit). This means that when the agent hangs up, the conference call will end for all participants.

Now, Twilio will make the call to the user and when that connects ask the new URL what to do with the call. This time you just need to respond with the TwiML to connect to the same conference. I'll leave that for you to deal with.

Finally, [to put participants on hold you need to use the REST API again](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#instance-post). You need to get the conference SID and the SID of the participant you want to put on hold. Since you will be putting the user on hold from your agent, you get both of these SIDs in the second webhook callback to your application.

With the conference and call SID, make a POST request like this:

```
    const string conferenceSid = "CONFERENCE_SID";
    const string callSid = "CALL_SID";
    ParticipantResource.Update(
        conferenceSid,
        callSid,
        hold: true,
        holdUrl: new Uri("http://example.com/hold")
    );
```

You can also provide a hold URL which can provide music while the user waits. For more information, [check the participant resource documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#instance-post). Unholding the user is the same process, but you set `hold` to `false`.

Let me know if this gets you on the way to creating this feature.